# Manage computer state with HDMI connection

Tags: windows-7, boot, hdmi, sleep

I have a windows 7 machine with [this motherboard](http://pcpartpicker.com/part/msi-motherboard-970ag46) and [this tv](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Emerson-LF320EM4F-32-720p-60Hz-LED-HDTV/32374191) that I would like to convert into a media center. I do not want the system running 100% of the time (trying to keep costs down) so I'm looking for ways to simplify this a bit. I'm wondering if any of these are possible and if so, how possible they are:

- Turn the computer on and off with an HDMI signal (as in, full off, full on when the TV turns on, off). I have an SSD, so load times are not a problem.
- Pull the computer out of sleep and put it back to sleep with an HDMI signal

If possible, I'd also like to use this drive as a NAS with an attached hard drive, but not keep the machine powered on.

I'd also be willing to entertain other solutions, aside from keeping it on 24/7. I'm trying to make an electric bill-friendly setup!

Comment: `Obviously I do not want the system running 100% of the time` - Why not?

Comment: @joeqwerty "I'm trying to make an electric bill-friendly setup!"

Comment: I run equipment at home consuming 8.93 kWh of electricity per day. My energy cost for said equipment is 62 cents a day. Turning off your one computer isn't likely to be any more electric bill friendly then just leaving it on. Id's say the cost savings you'll experience will be negligible to unnoticeable.

Comment: @joeqwerty That's fine, however it's also a bit noisy. I did neglect to mention these things but I just rather shut it down or put it to sleep than leave it running (hence the question).